FastReport.Data.MsSql 2024.2.19 references missing FastReport.dll
I've just updated my project to .net 8 and have updated all the NuGet packages for FastReport to the latest version.  I now get a compiler error that

"FastReport.Data.MsSql version 2024.2.19.0 uses FastReport version
2024.2.19.0 which has a higher version than referenced assembly FastReport 2024.2.14.0".

I tried to switch to FastReport.Data.OdbcDataConnection, but it has the same issue.  I think FastReport.dll has not been updated to version 2024.2.19.0
Since FastReport.dll is not directly referenced, is there a way to rethis?

Did you try updating all FastReport packages to the latest version?
